Is there a possible Ubuntu install on Apple Silicon hardware?
Is there possible Ubuntu install directly on Apple M1/2/3 CPU architecture aka Apple silicon.
I mean without virtual machine, and out of Asahi Linux which I already tried (it run well BTW) but its NOT ubuntu nor Debian based.
edit: it's OK for ubuntuasahi which I didn't knew about

I'd also explore the Asahi Project's work; https://github.com/UbuntuAsahi/ubuntu-asahi or even better on the Ubuntu Discourse & other Ubuntu sites (sorry I forget the exact links)

just added en adit in the question to precise Asahi linux is out of scope.

I think your best bet is the "Ubuntu Asahi" project here and here.
It is based on the parent project Asahi Linux, which is Fedora based, and may have better support. You can find its device support here.
Disclaimer:
I have not tested this, nor do I have any knowledge about Apple hardware whatsoever.

OK, I didn't knew about ubuntuasahi ... nice tips
